# In a treeView1 node select event why i'm getting null on the property Tag?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtParentName.Text = "";
        txtText.Text = "";
        txtTag.Text = "";

        txtName.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();
        txtText.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();
        txtTag.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
        txtParentName.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text.ToString();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

The null is on the line:

```
txtTag.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
```

Tag is null

> System.NullReferenceException was caught   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=ScrollLabel   StackTrace:
>          at ScrollLabelTest.DisplayResponses.treeView1_AfterSelect(Object sender,
>   TreeViewEventArgs e) in DisplayResponses.cs:line 58   InnerException:

Line 58 is:

```
txtTag.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
```

Is that normal that some nodes dosen't have a Tag ? Do i need to add a Tag to the nodes first ?

I took the example from here:

[TreeView](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/TreeviewBasics04152007195731PM/TreeviewBasics.aspx)

But he use form2 to give a new node name tag text...I don;t want to assign now each node and child node all this properties.

I understand now that i should give the node/s Name text, Parent Name text, Tag text. But i have like 70 nodes and in each node i expand and have more 50-70 nodes in each one. How can i give them all name tag and parent name ? What is the best logic of giving this names/text ?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal for objects in C# to have their default values (in this case `null`) if you did not set them.

So yes, if you did not explicitly set the `Tag` to something, it will be null. You will have to deal with it. Maybe with an `if`-statement, checking the value before you call a method on it.